Boolean problem?
I haven’t used Blender for a long time and, based on possibly incorrect memories (about how to use this modifier correctly), I remade the mesh that resulted from using the Boolean modifier, but received a distortion, which is visible in the first photo. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?
on my "new" mesh the color is different:


the mesh itself:

.blend file:


See if selecting 'A'll in Edit mode and using Shift-N to recalculate the normals cures the problem.

unfortunately, it didn't help

I think we'll need to see your Blend file in that case . You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Attached .blend file

Right-click . Shade Auto Smooth?

No, the artifacts still remain

It's probably because you have a giant Ngon on either side of your small octagonal shape (the one I'm assuming you booled into the larger mesh?). Try putting and edge loop on either side to connect it.

Yeah, this is it, thanks for the help everyone. I don't know how I didn't notice this)
